# VS2010 Performance Analysis: How can I identify Worker Threads? (CurrentThread.Name generates an exception)

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, performance-testing

How can identify the threads that are responsible for the Cross-Core context switches, and the 
 ones that are held up in synchronization?

(PS: I'm new to this part of Visual Studio... learning as I go, tips are appreciated!)

[image]

Various Stack traces of threads that spend most the time synchronizing and I don't know why:

**Thread 12384**

```
 Category = Synchronization Delay = 650947.5375 ms
 ntoskrnl.exe!SwapContext_PatchXRstor ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapContext
 ntoskrnl.exe!KiCommitThreadWait ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject
 ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
```

**Thread 8792**

```
 Category = Synchronization API = WaitForMultipleObjects
 Delay = 8993.9801 ms Unblocked by thread 3052; click 'Unblocking
 Stack' for details. kernel32.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjects@16
 clr.dll!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent
 clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker
 clr.dll!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer
 clr.dll!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload
 clr.dll!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload
 clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition
 clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase
 clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart
 clr.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
 kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12 ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8
 ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8


 The Unblocking stack for the above is

 Thread 8792 was unblocked by thread 3052 The unblocking call stack
 follows: ntoskrnl.exe! ?? ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
 ntoskrnl.exe!NtSetEvent ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
 wow64cpu.dll!CpupSyscallStub wow64cpu.dll!Thunk0Arg
 wow64.dll!RunCpuSimulation wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize ntdll.dll! ??
 ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string' ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk
 ntdll.dll!_ZwSetEvent@8 kernelbase.dll!_SetEvent@4
 clr.dll!CLREvent::Set clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space
 clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc
 clr.dll!Alloc clr.dll!FastAllocatePrimitiveArray clr.dll!JIT_NewArr1
 mscorlib.ni.dll![mscorlib.dll] mscorlib.ni.dll![mscorlib.dll]
 mscorlib.ni.dll![mscorlib.dll] mscorlib.ni.dll![mscorlib.dll]
 !0x206b89 system.core.ni.dll![<Unknown>]
 system.core.ni.dll![<Unknown>] system.core.ni.dll![<Unknown>]
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you zoom in as it suggests?

Comment: @chrisShain The thread ID doesn't give me any idea where it's coming from and the stack trace is WindowsOS code that I don't know...

Comment: I see (in the lower image) thread 1536 doing lots of work (green bar) while most of the other threads are tied up on synchronization (red bars). Also in that screenshot, it looks like you have selected a point in the green bar, and the message is "Multiple states in one pixel. Try zooming in".  When you zoom in, what is that thread (1536) doing?  My guess is that 1536 is holding a lock that the other (red bar) threads are waiting on.

Comment: What application is that as seen in the screenshots? If it is a window of visual studio, then where to find? I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite answering your exact question but the fastest way I have found in troubleshooting these issues is to get a process dump & then open up windbg.

The quick command for determining which threads are blocking is !syncblk, so something like the following should help in identifying the method calls which are blocking

> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\sos
>
> .chain
>
> !syncblk